# Finding Variance from a joint moment generating function

Tags: statistics, variance, moment-generating-functions, bivariate-distributions

The random vars X and Y have, for all real values of $T_1, T_2$, the joint mgf $M(T_1 , T_2) = \frac{1}{2} e^{T_1 +T_2} + \frac{1}{4} e^{2T_1 +T2} + \frac{1}{12}e^{T_2} + \frac{1}{6} e^{4T_1 +3T_2}$

I'm looking for V[X], but I believe that I am overlooking a way to simplify this problem. I know that variance is the second moment or the second derivative of the mgf,but I am not sure how to generate these derivatives and what to do after, given that it is a bivariate equation. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$M(t_1, t_2) = E(e^{t_1 X + t_2 Y})$$

$$M(t_1, 0) = E(e^{t_1X}) = \frac{1}{2}e^{t_1} + \frac{1}{4}e^{2t_1} + \frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{6}e^{4t_1} = M^{'}_{X}(t_1)$$

$$E(X^n) = \frac{\partial^n M^{'}_{X}(t_1)}{\partial t_1^n} \bigg\vert_{t_1=0}$$

$$\frac{\partial M^{'}_{X}(t_1)}{\partial t_1} = \frac{1}{2}e^{t_1} + \frac{2}{4}e^{2t_1} + \frac{4}{6}e^{4t_1}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 M^{'}_{X}(t_1)}{\partial t_1^2} = \frac{1}{2}e^{t_1} + \frac{4}{4}e^{2t_1} + \frac{16}{6}e^{4t_1}$$

$$Var(X) = E(X^2)-E(X)^2 = (1/2 + 4/4 + 16/6) - (1/2 + 2/4 + 4/6)^2 = 25/18$$

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. But as an extension, how might one use this to find, say P(X<Y)? is it something similar as simply just setting the other to zero as we evaluate one of them?

Comment: @user455681 Unfortunately not.  While the mgf (usually?) determines the distribution of the variables, the information that it leaves directly accessible is just (joint) expectations of powers, so if what you want to know can't be read off from the Taylor series for the mgf, then it is a subtle problem trying to figure it out.  If you have ever played around with generating functions before, you know that certain things are easy to say, but others are hard, and that's just how it is.  Like any other mathematical tool, it is important to know what mgf's make easy.

Comment: @Aaron I think I misunderstood, so, given the information we have, which leads us to expectations of powers, we cannot deduce P(X<Y)? Though I know the first 4 moments wouldn't help us here directly, is there no way of manipulating the expected value to provide something that we could compare and thus compute a probability. Sorry for the questions, I'm studying for the actuarial P exam and am struggling with bivariate distributions.

Comment: @user455681 I wouldn't say that we *can't* deduce it (because in theory we could recover the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$), but rather that it isn't obvious how to do so (to me, at least).  I should say, though, that the joint mgf of X and Y immediately yields the mgf if X-Y (or, indeed, of any $aX+bY$) which reduces the problem to determining  $P(Z>0)$ from the mgf of $Z=X-Y$. This is an "easier" problem, but off the top of my head I still don't see a solution.

Comment: @user455681 Apologies, I misspoke.  Because of the specific form of your mgf, you CAN easily determine the distribution of $X-Y$ (see heropup's answer), and thus you know the probabilities you want.  However, for random variables that can take on an infinite number of values (or continuous values), the problem is not so easy.

Comment: @HRM4321 Check this answer for a generalized procedure to obtain $P(X<Y)$ given the joint characteristic function of $X$ and $Y$. link: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2338310/97188

Answer (score 0):

Even more simply, you know from the form of the MGF that $X$ and $Y$ are joint discrete random variables:  it is easy to see that 
$$\begin{align*}\Pr[(X,Y) = (1,1)] &= \frac{1}{2}, \\
\Pr[(X,Y) = (2,1)] &= \frac{1}{4}, \\
\Pr[(X,Y) = (0,1)] &= \frac{1}{12}, \\
\Pr[(X,Y) = (4,3)] &= \frac{1}{6}, \\
\end{align*}$$ and $0$ for any other values.  Thus, the variance of $X$ is simply $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \left(\frac{1^2}{2} + \frac{2^2}{4} + \frac{4^2}{6} \right) - \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{4} + \frac{4}{6}\right)^2 = \frac{25}{18}.$$