# Given a joint characteristic function, find $P(X<Y)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

This question was asked in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2334281/given-a-joint-moment-generating-function-find-pxy#comment4810189_2334281) before for a given MGF with discrete r.v.. A partial solution for the generalized version of the problem was given in this link by expiTTp1z0. But that is not nearly enough.

> Question:
>
> A joint characteristic function of $(X,Y)$ is given, find $P(X<Y)$.

Comment: I think you will make the question a bit more attractive by just asking for an expression for $P(Z>0)$ on base of the MGF of $Z$. You can immediately apply that on $Z:=Y-X$ whose MGF can be expressed by means to the MGF of $(X,Y)$.

Comment: @drhab what do you mean by " ...MGF can be expressed by means to the MGF of $(X,Y)$", btw I changed MGF to Ch.f , since MGF may not exists always.

Comment: If $N$ denotes the MGF of $Z=Y-X$ and $M$ the MGF of $(X,Y)$ then $N(t)=\mathbb Ee^{t(Y-X)}=M(-t,t)$. Sortlike for characteristic functions.

Comment: Okk, that part!! In the link I gave expiTTp1z0 gave a partial solution, which includes what you @drhab said, but that is not nearly enough.

Comment: It is not enough but you can use it to simplify your question. Btw, have you taken a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae) allready? You can find CDF by means of the theorem of Gil-Pilaez. That gives you an expression for $P(Z>0)=1-F_Z(0)$.

Comment: Personally I never encountered any use of finding CDF on base of characteristic function. It is allready enough to know that there is a one-to-one relation between them. Has someone asked you to find $P(X<Y)$ this way, or are you just curious about it?

Comment: @drhab it started when I saw that problem, and I thought there must a generalization of this problem, since I knew there is a $1-1$ relation between Ch.f and CDF. wiki page is helpful though, I see it is somehow related to f**ourier transform**, can you help me with better link or book, in this matter?

Comment: It is the best to finish this conversation by now. Sorry, but I am not really familiar with Fourier transforms and stuff like that, and have no further valuable links/references for you. Good luck with it.

Comment: @MANMAID Thanks for raising the question. I think I got it now (based on the wiki link provided by @drhab). So, $\phi_{Z}(t) = \phi_{X,Y}(-t,t)$. Then by the wiki link, $f_{Z}(z)$ is nothing but the inverse fourier transform of $\phi_{Z}(t)$, after which one may obtain $F_{Z}(z)$. If you allow I can try adding an answer here with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the example of the joint MGF from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2334281/97188) question,

$$M_{X,Y}(t_1,t_2) = \frac{1}{2}e^{t_1+t_2} + \frac{1}{4}e^{2t_1+t_2} + \frac{1}{12}e^{t_2} + \frac{1}{6}e^{4t_1+3t_2}$$

The joint characterisitic function of $X$ and $Y$ is,

$$\phi_{X,Y}(t_1,t_2) = M_{X,Y}(it_1,it_2) = \frac{1}{2}e^{i(t_1+t_2)} + \frac{1}{4}e^{i(2t_1+t_2)} + \frac{1}{12}e^{it_2} + \frac{1}{6}e^{i(4t_1+3t_2)}$$

Define $Z = Y-X$, then the characteristic function of $Z$ is,

$$\phi_{Z}(t) = \phi_{X,Y}(-t,t) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}e^{-it} + \frac{1}{12}e^{it} + \frac{1}{6}e^{-it}$$

By the inverse fourier transform of $\phi_{Z}(z)$, we obtain pdf $f_{Z}(z)$,

$$\begin{align}f_{Z}(z) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-itz}\phi_{Z}(t)dt\\\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-itz}(\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{4}e^{-it} + \frac{1}{12}e^{it} + \frac{1}{6}e^{-it})dt \right)\\\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{-itz} + \frac{1}{4}e^{-it(z+1)}+\frac{1}{12}e^{-it(z-1)}+\frac{1}{6}e^{-it(z+1)}\right)dt\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\delta(z) + \frac{1}{4}\delta(z+1)+\frac{1}{12}\delta(z-1)+\frac{1}{6}\delta(z+1)\end{align}$$

where $\delta(z-c) = 1 \text{ when } z-c = 0$.

From here, one can easily find $F_{Z}(z)$.

Overall the steps are,

- Compute joint characteristic function $\phi_{X,Y}(t_1, t_2)$.
- Define $Z = Y - X$ and compute characteristic function of $Z$, $\phi_{Z}(t) = \phi_{X,Y}(-t,t)$.
- Compute the inverse fourier transform of $\phi_{Z}(t)$ to obtain $f_{Z}(z)$.
- Using $f_{Z}(z)$ compute the cdf $F_{Z}(z)$.

Thanks @drhab for [this wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae).

Helpful link: computing last integrals leading to dirac delta functions, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Comment: Thanks a lot...